# Java float to a double and create the correct the format

Tags: java

Ths may well be a simple question.

I am having an issue with a timestamp which is represented as:

long timestamp: 351802384172493

I need to pass my timeStamp as a double, when i create the double it is represented as:

double timestamp: 3.15802384172493E14

I actually need to pass the double in this format:

double timestamp: 315802.384172493

Is there a best way to achieve this?

Comment: Neither `long` nor `double` contain any information about formatting. You have to provide it while you print it.

Comment: So ... what's your reason for passing this long to double?

Comment: Thanks the answer below works. Much appreciated i did wonder if there was any other way that just dividing by a big number, but it does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your long to double by dividing it by the correct factor

```
long timestamp = 351802384172493L;   
double ts = timestamp / 1_000_000_000.0;

System.out.printf("%.9f\n", ts);
```

yields

> 351802.384172493